# Areas to mask when painting a bike

Tags: paint

This summer, I'm going to buy a BMX bike because I've wanted one for a while, and I have zero self control. I'm going to paint it because first off, the color is kinda boring, and second, spray painting things is fun. The bike is a Kink Gap XL (2021 model) and the paint is from Spray.Bike. So, when I paint it, I'm gonna have a friend disassemble it for me (because I don't trust myself to do it) and then I'm gonna mask it. So, other than inside all the holes, like where the stem and crank go, and the slots for the wheels (on the end of the fork and back of the frame) what else do I have to mask? I cant think of anything else, but I'm probably forgetting something. Thanks!

Comment: As a general guideline: Don't paint over anything that doesn't already have paint. If you follow that, I can't think of any possible pitfalls.

Comment: Haha yeah thats probably a good rule to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First up - consider buying a bike in the colour you want.  That will be the easiest/cheapest solution.

---

Anything with threads (internal or external) and anywhere that has flat machined surfaces for nuts/bolts to tighten against should be masked to prevent paint.  If you do paint surfaces like dropouts, the paint will crack and flake off quickly.

You should also mask off anything you want to stay chromed, and remove all parts like groupset, bottom bracket, seatpost, bars, stem, cables, etc.

The best paint job comes from a completely blank frame, so remove all decals/stickers and wash the bike to remove any oils.  Then scuff the existing paint with sandpaper all over to give the new paint somewhere to tooth into.

I would also strongly recommend you take lots of **before** photos and post them here, along with the serial number.  In the future someone might come along asking to identify their dirty old BMX that was overpainted decades ago.

Progress and post-painting photos might be cool too.

Do consider that this painting will void any and all warranty as well.